# javascript validator not working, just returning it passed when it didn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Here is my code, I compared it to this site which has the script working and I can't seem to spot the difference why mine is not working. I am probably missing something simple.

This is the site I got the script from but instructions are a little vague:
http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/

This is someone with a working example:
http://www.boutiqueapartments.com/index.php/contact/test

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- Main style sheet-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/stylesheet.css"/>
<!-- Validation script-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bugs/javascript/validate.min.js"></script>

<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="success_box">All of the fields were successfully validated!</div>
<div class="error_box"></div>
<div id="container">
    <form name="create_bug" id="create_bug" method="post" action="bug_create.php" onSubmit="return FormValidator()">
    <div class="fm-req">
        <label for="bug_description">Bug Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="bug_title" id="bug_title" value="" size="78" maxlength="250">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new FormValidator('create_bug', [{
    name: 'bug_title',
    display: 'bug title',    
    rules: 'required'
}], function(errors, event) {
    var SELECTOR_ERRORS = $('.error_box'),
        SELECTOR_SUCCESS = $('.success_box');

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        SELECTOR_ERRORS.empty();
        SELECTOR_ERRORS.append(errors.join('<br />'));

        SELECTOR_SUCCESS.css({ display: 'none' });
        SELECTOR_ERRORS.fadeIn(200);
    }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

All I get returned even if its blank is "all fields have successfully passed" or "Object object", any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors is an object array, Can't simple join.
Try

```
new FormValidator('create_bug', [ {
    name : 'bug_title',
    display : 'bug title',
    rules : 'required'
} ], function(errors, event) {
    var SELECTOR_ERRORS = $('.error_box'), SELECTOR_SUCCESS = $('.success_box');

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        var errorString = '';
        $.each(errors, function(i, e) {
            errorString += e.message + '<br />';
        })

        SELECTOR_ERRORS.empty();
        SELECTOR_ERRORS.html(errorString);

        SELECTOR_SUCCESS.css({
            display : 'none'
        });
        SELECTOR_ERRORS.fadeIn(200);
    }
});
```

and fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sya2m/).